# How to append options to an existing .meta:n l3key?

Tags: l3keys

If I have previously set up a `.meta:n` key with

```
\keys_define:nn { module } { key .meta:n = { … } }
```

then it's easy to replace the key with new values by calling `\kerys_define:nn` with new `meta` options.

But what if I want to append to the current meta options for the key?

### MWE

In this MWE, I want `\setstyle` to replace the meta options for `style` and `\setstyle*` to append to the meta options for `style`. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { dcp }
  { 
    keya .tl_set:N = \l__dcp_keya_tl ,
    keyb .tl_set:N = \l__dcp_keyb_tl ,
    keyc .tl_set:N = \l__dcp_keyc_tl ,
    style .choice:
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \setstyle { s m }
  {
    \bool_if:NTF #1
      {
        % how can I append to style?
      }
      {
        % set style
        \keys_define:nn { dcp } { style .meta:n = {#2} }
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \showstyle { }
  {
    \keys_show:nn { dcp } { style }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\setstyle{keya=x,keyb=y}
\begin{document}
\showstyle
\setstyle{keya=x,keyb=yy}
\showstyle
\setstyle*{keyc=z}
\showstyle
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have an off-topic question: Is there any advantage to using `\bool_if:NTF #1` as a substitute for `\IfBooleanTF{#1}` when testing whether a function defined by `\NewDocumentCommand` is starred or unstarred?

Comment: @User23456234, I don't think so. But all this code will live in an Expl3 style so I'm just using the Expl3 interface rather than the LaTeX one.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if there is an official interface, but storing the keys as a clist seems to work. I had to change the `\showstyle` command because with the way I've defined `\setstyle`, `\keys_show:nn` just shows

```
>  code  =>  \keys_set:nV {dcp}\l_dcp_style_clist
```

which is not very helpful. Also, I would fully understand if this is not what you had in mind...

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { dcp }
  { 
    keya .tl_set:N = \l__dcp_keya_tl ,
    keyb .tl_set:N = \l__dcp_keyb_tl ,
    keyc .tl_set:N = \l__dcp_keyc_tl ,
    %style .choice:
  }
\clist_new:N \l_dcp_style_clist
\NewDocumentCommand \setstyle { s m }
  {
    \bool_if:NTF #1
      {
        % append to style
        \clist_put_right:Nn \l_dcp_style_clist { #2 }
      }
      {
        % set style
        \clist_set:Nn \l_dcp_style_clist { #2 }
      }
    \keys_define:nn { dcp }
      {
        style .code:n = \keys_set:nV { dcp } \l_dcp_style_clist
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \showstyle { }
  {
    \keys_set:nn { dcp } { style }
    \l__dcp_keya_tl
    \l__dcp_keyb_tl
    \l__dcp_keyc_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\setstyle{keya=x,keyb=y}

\showstyle

\setstyle{keya=x,keyb=yy}

\showstyle

\setstyle*{keyc=z}

\showstyle

\end{document}
```

I've not benchmarked but it's possible precompiling offers some speed benefit; you could change the definition of `\setstyle` to

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \keys_precompile:nnN { nV }
\NewDocumentCommand \setstyle { s m }
  {
    \bool_if:NTF #1
      {
        % append to style
        \clist_put_right:Nn \l_dcp_style_clist { #2 }
      }
      {
        % set style
        \clist_set:Nn \l_dcp_style_clist { #2 }
      }
    \keys_precompile:nVN { dcp } \l_dcp_style_clist \l_dcp_stylekeys_tl
    \keys_define:nn { dcp }
      {
        style .code:n = \l_dcp_stylekeys_tl
      }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, saving previous settings is my current option. But sometimes I miss features of `l3keys`.

Comment: @DavidPurton Which features in particular? From responses to my [own questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/696754/208544) it seems to me the goal of l3keys is not to do all the key operations (like append) at the key level like pgfkeys

Comment: Features I might not know about :)

Comment: @DavidPurton Ah homonyms :-)

Comment: Ooo. I see how you read me :D